# Is there a resource/paper containing information about which co-activators are often associated with a given transcription factor?

Tags: transcription, gene-regulation, transcription-factor

Given a list of human transcription factors, I would be interested in which co-activators they are often associated with.

I imagine that one could combine co-expression, pull-down, and other kinds of data to get an idea here.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, your question isn't focused, isn't clear, and shows no evidence of the expected prior research — all of these are reasons for closure and downvoting. Please [edit] this to focus on a narrow (i.e. answerable in this format) question, tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions.

Comment: In addition, if you provide context (e.g. you are trying to develop a bioinformatic tool to do *X*) you are more likely to get a useful answer. In addition, depending on context this question might be a better fit for [Bioinformatics.SE], but if you think so please do **not** [crosspost](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/), instead request migration or delete from this site before reposting (with more details as described above) there.

Comment: related chapter:  Coactivators  •Encyclopedia of Cancer, 2008• Vol.1, p.714-714

Comment: useful information:  https://www.mdpi.com/2072-6694/12/8/2296/htm

Answer (score 1):

This website can be used to search for protein interactomes:

http://www.interactome-atlas.org/

might help you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Most eukaryotic TFs (transcription factors) are thought to act by recruiting cofactors (Reiter et al., 2017).

> “Coactivators” and “corepressors,” are cofactors and these are mediators of TF effector activity.

Do you mean you need the information of *cofactors*?